# Twitter bootstrap using wells (safari vs chrome)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone help me understand why would wells correctly in Safari and not correctly (overlapping) in Chrome?

This is how it looks in Chrome https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkfbr.png

Basically the wells are overlapping in Chrome. (on top of each other)

The code is simply

```
  <div class='row-fluid'>
        <div class='span4'>
          <div class='well well-large' style='width:100%; display:table; background:#ffffff;'>
            <b>Hosts Down</b>
             data
          </div>
          <div class='well well-large' style='width:100%; display:table; background:#ffffff;'>
            <b>Critical Services</b>
              data
          </div>
          <div class='well well-large' style='width:100%; display:table; background:#ffffff;'>
            <b>Links</b>
               data
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='span8'>
          <div class='well well-large' style='width:100%; display:table; background:#ffffff; text-align:center;'>
            graphs
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: post the links to the screenshots and someone will edit them in for you

Comment: It works for me in Chrome (no overlap): http://jsfiddle.net/Xqxgy/1/ Maybe you should specify version and OS.

Comment: Mac OS Chrome: Version 28.0.1500.95. so it works fine in jsfiddle hmm

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/OOeTw8b.png this is how it looks in Chrome

Comment: It's likely something else in your code since it works isloated in jsFiddle. Not sure it matters a lot, but Bootstrap 2 right? Not version 3?

Comment: right, haven't upgraded yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s just a guess, but looking at your code I’d imagine it’s because of your inline styles. You’re specifying a width of 100%, but the wells will also have padding, which will add up to more than 100% of the parent container.

And in saying that, don’t use inline styles.

Comment: What's an "inline style"? Sorry I'm new to CSS

Comment: `<div style="…">`. CSS should ideally be an external style sheet, otherwise you’ve got to go through your HTML by hand and update each and every `style` attribute.

Comment: oh okay that's what you meant! yes I will go thru it all day today.

Comment: If I don't use the width 100% it wraps around and doesn't look nice anymore http://jsfiddle.net/Xqxgy/2/

Comment: It’s because you’re setting the `display` mode to `table`. Why are you doing that? Just leave it as `block`.